# Unit testing of destructive functions in lisp

Tags: unit-testing, common-lisp

The background here is that I have a non-destructive version of a function that I want to make destructive for performance reasons. However, writing unit tests gets challenging because lisp considers all quoted lists in the source code to be constants and changing those leads to undefined behaviour.

I'm using parachute as the unit testing framework

e.g.,

```
(define-test suite-1
 (let ((start '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
       (end '((7 1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
  (is #'equal end (push 7 (car start))))
 (let ((start '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
       (end '((8 1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
  (is #'equal end (push 8 (car start)))))
```

This kinda fails because we end up pushing `8` onto the constant list `(1 2)` which eventually causes `(push 8 (car start))` to result in `(8 7 1 2)` instead of the expected `(8 1 2)`

This isn't a problem with testing non-destructive functions because they don't modify constants. This is also not a problem outside of unit tests because I know that the original structure will no longer be needed.

I could replace the above with this ugly thing :-

```
(let ((start (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4) (list 5 6))) ...
```

which then creates a proper non-constant list but it sure does make the code unreadable...

Any suggestions on how other people approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `COPY-TREE` to make a deep copy of the quoted list structure.

```
(let ((start (copy-tree '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))))
  ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example has several mistakes.

```
(define-test suite-1
 (let ((start '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
       (end '((7 1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
  (is #'equal end (push 7 (car start))))
 (let ((start '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
       (end '((8 1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
  (is #'equal end (push 8 (car start)))))
```

These are two independent `let` expressions. Meaning,
the `start` in the first expression - no matter what destructive function you apply on it - can't affect the `start` in the second expression.
Since inbetween, it got newly created using the same quoted list expression.

Second, `(push 7 (car start))` doesn't return the entire `start` content, thus just it returns only the modified `car` of `start`.
Therefore, you can't compare it with `end` but you should compare it to `(car end)` for `equal`ity.
If you do that, your code should run through.
I tested it by:

```
  (defun test ()
    (let ((start '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
          (end '((7 1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
      (assert (equal (car end) (push 7 (car start)))))
    (let ((start '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6)))
          (end '((8 1 2) (3 4) (5 6))))
      (assert (equal (car end) (push 8 (car start)))))
    (print "successfully run through."))
;; and then run:
(test)
;; 
;; "successfully run through." 
'' "successfully run through."
```

So the `assert`s were fulfilled.

SBCL warns about applying destructive function on constant data. But the constant data applies only wihin the `let` expression you are using. But outside of it, in a new `let` expression, a `'((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))` would produce the same list always.

I couldn't believe when I saw your example that - if you would use `(car end)` to test for `equal`ity, that it would give in the second expression anything else than `T`.

#### The `start` in the first `let`'s scope has nothing to do with the `start` in the second `let`'s scope

You can easily prove it by:

```
(eq '((1 2) (3 4)) '((1 2) (3 4)))
;; => NIL
```

So with every redefinition of a literal object, you create a new entity in a new place. Thus mutations of the first `start` can't affect the second `start` which is freshly defined in a new scope (`let` expression).

This is why I criticize your example - which would only make sense if the same literal refers to the same place.

#### So I was wrong

@adabsurdum in the comments gave even the link to a discussion about this behavior that some implementations even collapse literal objects into one - according to CLtL. Thank you for being patient and explaining this all to me!!

Comment: _"But the constant data applies only within the `let` expression you are using...."_ Do you have some reference in the Hyperspec for this? AFAIK attempts to destructively modify literal data always lead to undefined consequences as far as the CL standard is concerned.

Comment: Fair point but that was not the gist of the question. The gist of it was around destructively modifying constant data even if it's scoped within a let. @adabsurdum has the right idea of what I was trying to ask...

Comment: @adabsurdum is it really like this? I doubt that if you start from a `'((1 2) (4 5))` in a new expression - a new let expression - and do exactly defined destructions in the same order - that you would end up with different results when applying the same steps. I mean if that would be the case, Lisp as a language would be useless. Or can you give an example which shows a case where Lisp does sth very unlogical?

Comment: @owagh - yes, but what you wanted to ask is within one `let` expression. I just wanted to point out your example is confusing for helpers - because not constructed correctly. - @adabsurdum luckily understood what you actually meant. - but other readers like me would be puzzled by the example. and I was just pointing out for this case.

Comment: _"Lisp as a language would be useless."_ -- @Gwang-JinKim that does not make sense. We are talking about constant objects, not all objects. The CL spec explicitly says that attempts to mutate such objects results in undefined behavior. My understanding is that implementations are _allowed_ to use the same object for all list literals of the form `'((1 2) (4 5))` because user code which adheres to the spec will not attempt to modify constant objects.

Comment: @adabsurdum it does - if Lisp would behave like this example suggests - like `(let ((start '((1 2) (4 5)))) ..do..mutations)` and then `(let ((start '((1 2) (3 4)))) ..do.other.mutations)` and if the second let-expressions content would be in any way affected by first let-expression. both `start` variables are totally independent from each other. But his example pretended that the second let would be in any form affected. which is not true.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim -- I meant that _"Lisp as a language would be useless"_ doesn't make sense because it is easy to avoid this problem by creating fresh list data with `list` or `copy-tree`. `let` restricts the binding of `start` to the scope of the `let` expression, but each independently scoped `start` may be bound to the same constant object. The spec says that you can't do this sort of mutation. Unless you know of some exception to [this](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_ga.htm) in the spec.

Comment: @adabsurdum I get your point - and I really love your `copy-tree` trick - definitely sth I will apply from now on. Thanks for that! And I am a fan of common lisp. I don't mean Lisp is actually useless. What I mean is that the literal definition of an object doesn't refer to the same object: `(eq '((1 2) (3 4)) '((1 2) (3 4)))` returns `NIL` - so every new literal is a completely new object. that is that when redefining in a new `let` scope one starts with a fresh object. Thus mutations of the "same" literal in one `let` scope can't affect the that of the other scope.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim -- _"so every new literal is a completely new object"_ is not true. It may be true for some implementations at some times, but this is not required by the CL spec. [There is some discussion of the issue here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Issues/iss083_w.htm). In particular, in SBCL if I do `(defvar x '(1 2 (3 4)))` and `(defvar y '(1 2 (3 4)))` in a file, compile that file and check in the REPL, the constants have been collapsed so that `(eq x y)` evaluates to `T`. A different result follows when doing all of this in the REPL instead of in a compiled file.

Comment: @adabsurdum Thank you so much! I learned sth important by this. Thank you for your patience and explaining it to me and finding even this link!